# How to get elevated permission to edit a registry CLSID, with in a WiX fragment

Tags: windows, wix, registry, ifilter, clsid

I am trying to set windows desktop search to use a different html filter other than the system default filter(nlhtml.dll). When I look up the PersistentHandler (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.html\PersistentHandler`) it points to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{eec97550-47a9-11cf-b952-00aa0051fe20}`.

I want to change the value of above clsid. Following is the WiX snippet

```
<?define PersistentHandler_HtmlIFilter="eec97550-47a9-11cf-b952-00aa0051fe20"?>

<RegistryValue Action="write" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{$(var.PersistentHandler_HtmlIFilter)}" Value="MY HTML Persistent Handler" Type="string" />
```

But the value is not changed.

Regarding permission;
Only TrustedInstaller has full control of this entry. Administrator, SYSTEM and other users only have read permission.

How can I get elevated permission to make this registry change using WiX. This is part of a larger project and I am only editing a fragment of WiX script (`<Fragment>.. </Fragment>`).

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. Registry keys limited to TrustedInstaller indicate keys that are protected by [Windows Resource Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wfp/windows-resource-protection-portal). Windows Installer will not modify these keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Advanced Run](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html), In program to run, Go to C:/windows/regedit.exe

In the Run As box, click Trusted Installer and then run on the bottom.
Now it's running with TI privileges and you can do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try [PC Hunter](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/pc_hunter.html) or [Power Run](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/powerrun.html), and run `regedit` with it, and run it with system privileges, and you can do what you like.